# Unable to find videos cache for youtube videos in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, browser-cache

I have watched a video on youtube, I didn't close the browser window and it is buffered. I can watch that video anytime, without connecting to internet, as it is completely buffered.
But I am not able to find the local cache for it, I checked the default folder of cache for my browser(chrome), which is: %AppData% Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache, but videos is not there. However it must be there somewhere in my local system as I am able to watch it again and again without connecting to internet.
I used to get those previously, but something happen either it is saving in some other folder or what.
 does anyone has any idea?

Comment: You can read this [How To Copy YouTube Video or FLV File From Google Chrome Cache Folder?](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/09/21/how-to-copy-youtube-video-or-flv-file-from-google-chrome-cache-folder/) post

Comment: Not all video cache goes in that directory, esp. Incognito ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the location at last, It seems the new google chrome has changed the location for Flash temporary files, instead of using the old location for cache files

> ...AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

it is using the below new location:

> ...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash

However I am not sure if it is keeping all files there or only big files (say 100Mbs or more).

Thanks for help!

**Update March 2018**

Now a days, in most cases, youtube doesn't buffer complete video at once, it buffers in chunks as you watch. Pause the video, the buffering will also be paused.

Also, youtube, uses two [WebM streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM), one for video and other for audio. These both webM streams will be in cache as separate files. So we have to combine both to watch a video, or play both to watch the video. (But if you fallback to old browser which doesn't support WebM, youtube will fallback to MP4)

Again, not sure if browser is keeping the old chunks of the these files or not, but even if it is keeping, its very hard to find all those right chunks and combine them.

However, if you still interested, chrome uses below cache locations:

> C:/Users/.../AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
>   C:/Users/.../AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Media Cache\

Comment: Rahul, from my testing it appears the cached files go into "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache" initially. Once they reach a certain size they are moved to the folder you identified. Not sure what the exact size is that triggers the move. The best I can tell is that it happens at around 40 MB.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with chrome. It works only with IE. Also it doesn't work with the new Vevo player. You may download IDM or any other app for downloading videos.

Comment: May be chrome caches is somewhere else or using smaller chunks of multiple files. Not sure

Comment: What is "it"? Please make your answer clear(er).

Comment: Cache must be somewhere in my system, may be in smaller chunks of files...right

Comment: 'It' refers to finding the video cache file in your browser's cache folder.

Comment: Yes, it may be in smaller chunks. And even if u find those chunks how are you going to merge them into a single file ?

Comment: In my cache folder there are several files of 100Kb to 200Kb, i think those cannot be videos files, my video files should be at least greater then 500Kb or 1Mb, I tried playing all the files whatsoever the size, but no luck :(

Comment: As I said, may be chrome is breaking it into smaller chunks. Use video downloading application. I suggest IDM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rakz, I will try to use that video downloader.
Just have curiosity, cant I play those smaller chunks in my VLC?

Comment: Yes if they are caches of video files then you can play it with vlc. Vlc can play broken files.

Comment: Hi Rakz, it was not breaking in smaller chunks, but changed the location..i just added answer for same...thank anyway :)